# Сумма внутри столбца pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Есть DataFrame из трех столбцов, цена и коэффициенты.

```
     price     k1        k2
0    21931.37  0.266667  0.733333
1    21976.18  0.266667  0.733333
2    21983.26  0.266667  0.733333
3    21967.10  0.266667  0.733333
4    21883.39  0.266667  0.733333
```

Необходимо добавить столбец, значения строк которых будет равен cумме произведения цены с первым коэффициентом и предыдущего значения i1 со вторым коэффициентом

```
df['i1'] = df['k1']*df["price"] + df['k2']*df['i1'].shift(1)
```

Приводит к ошибке KeyError: 'i1'.

Если обозначить D['i1'] = 0

```
     price     k1        k2           i1
0    21931.37  0.266667  0.733333     NaN
1    21976.18  0.266667  0.733333     5860.314667
2    21983.26  0.266667  0.733333     5862.202667
3    21967.10  0.266667  0.733333     5857.893333
4    21883.39  0.266667  0.733333     5835.570667
```

Значение равно произведению цены с первым коэффициентом без суммы с предыдущим значением строки.
Помогите, только начал вникать в работу с pandas.

Comment: Обозначьте где какая колонка в ваших данных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему. Создал столбец со значением нуля и перезаписал значение через цикл.

```
df['i1'] = 0
for i in range(len(df)):
    if i == 0:
       df.loc[i, 'i1'] = df['price'][i] * df['k1'][i]
    if i > 0:
       df.loc[i, 'i1'] = df['price'][i] * df['k1'][i] + df['i1'][i-1] * df['k2'][i]
```

Comment: Да, если нужно последовательно пересчитывать строки в зависимости от предыдущих расчётов, то без цикла не выйдет.

Comment: Может есть более простое построение цикла?

Answer (score 2):

Вы используете в вычислениях колонку, которой у вас еще нет. разумеется, получаете ошибку.

```
df["i1"] = (df["price"]*df["k1"]+df["price"]
            .shift(1)*df["k1"].shift(1)*df["k2"]).fillna(df["price"]*df["k1"])
```

df:

```
      price        k1        k2            i1
0  21931.37  0.266667  0.733333   5848.372644
1  21976.18  0.266667  0.733333  10149.126648
2  21983.26  0.266667  0.733333  10159.777502
3  21967.10  0.266667  0.733333  10156.852698
4  21883.39  0.266667  0.733333  10131.369823
```

Comment: В таком случае в строке с индексом 2 и далее принимается значение i1[0]

Comment: Ошибся в написании условия.

Answer (score 1):

если хочется уложиться в одну строку, то можно еще вот так "изпитониться":

```
df.assign(i1=df.price * df.k1).assign(i1=lambda x: x.i1 + x.i1.shift().fillna(0) * x.k2)

>>> out
'''
      price        k1        k2            i1
0  21931.37  0.266667  0.733333   5848.372644
1  21976.18  0.266667  0.733333  10149.126648
2  21983.26  0.266667  0.733333  10159.777502
3  21967.10  0.266667  0.733333  10156.852698
4  21883.39  0.266667  0.733333  10131.369823
```